# Make trouble: it tries to link before compiling anything

Tags: c++, makefile

I get multiple error messages, saying that none of the object files exist. Isn't make supposed to handle the dependencies and compile the sources first?

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS =

###############################
# Define header file variables
###############################

# Application

accuser = Accuser.h $(agent)
game = Game.h $(roomMgr) $(accuser)

# Actions
action = Action.h $(common) $(object) $(condition) $(goal) $(orderedPair) $(IExecutable)
actionList = ActionList.h $(stab) $(goTo) $(take) $(drop) $(bludgeon) $(strangle) $(shoot) $(waitFor)
actionMgr = ActionManager.h $(action) $(actionList) $(common)
actionRecord = ActionRecord.h
IExecutable = IExecutable.h $(common)
bludgeon = Bludgeon.h $(murder) $(agent)
drop = Drop.h $(action)
goTo = GoTo.h $(action) $(agent)
murder = Murder.h $(action) $(agent)
shoot = Shoot.h $(murder) $(agent)
stab = Stab.h $(murder) $(agent)
strangle = Strangle.h $(murder) $(agent)
take = Take.h $(action)
waitFor = WaitFor.h $(action) $(agent)
```

And a few more variable definitions, then the targets:

```
###############################
# Define dependencies
###############################

# Application

objects = $(game_obj) $(action_obj) $(condition_obj) $(object_obj) $(prop_obj) \
 $(operator_obj) $(plangning_obj) $(world_obj) $(utilities_obj)

sauce : $(objects) $(action) $(game)
    $(CXX) -o sauce $(objects)

Game.o : $(game) $(all_props) $(operationMgr) $(aciton)
Game_InitializeObjects.o : $(common) $(game) $(all_props)

game_obj = Game.o Game_InitializeObjects.o

# Actions

Action.o : $(action) $(agent) $(room) $(operatorMgr) $(roomMgr)
ActionManager.o : $(actionMgr)
Bludgeon.o : $(bludgeon) $(roomMgr)
Drop.o : $(drop) $(prop) $(room) $(roomMgr) $(agent)
GoTo.o : $(goTo) $(room) $(roomMgr)
Murder.o : $(murder) $(roomMgr) $(room) $(factMgr)
Shoot.o : $(shoot) $(roomMgr)
Stab.o : $(Stab) $(roomMgr)
Strangle.o : $(strangle) $(roomMgr) $(room)
Take.o : $(take) $(roomMgr) $(room) $(agent) $(prop)
Waitfor.o : $(waitfor) $(room) $(roomMgr)

action_obj = Action.o ActionManager.o Bludgeon.o Drop.o GoTo.o Murder.o Shoot.o Stab.o \
Strangle.o Take.o WaitFor.o
```

And then some more targets.

Comment: Certainly. If you want help you need to post the Makefile.

Comment: You've elided the most important content with your "a few more variable definitions".  The critical content for your problem is the definition of the various `$(game_obj)`, `$(action_obj)`, etc. variables.  Those are the ones on the prerequisite list of `sauce` so those are the ones determining whether the objects are built before `sauce` or not.

Comment: Also it makes no sense to have the executable target, `sauce`, depend on the header files like `$(action)` and `$(game)`.  Executables should depend only on object files; each object file should depend on the associated source file and header files.

Comment: Where do you have the source files (the .C, .cc, or .cpp) in your project?

Comment: @PeterSW They are all in the same directory as the makefile

Comment: What do you get if you run make with just one of the objects as the target, For example: `make ActionManager.o`?

Comment: It runs "g++ -c -o ActionManger.o ActionManager.cpp"

Comment: Could you give the actual error message, it would help a lot with understanding what the problem is?

Comment: OK, I moved all the variable definitions to before the rule definitions and it works now.
What I don't understand is that before this, the command in the "sauce" rule was receiving the correct arguments even though they depended on variables that were all defined after the "objects" variable and the "sauce" rule.

Answer (score 0):

So we have established that the Makefile is able to compile the .cpp files into the object files using a [built in implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

> I get multiple error messages, saying that none of the object files exist. Isn't make supposed to handle the dependencies and compile the sources first?

These must be from the compiler rather than make. (Would be much easier to debug if I could see them!)

So then the problem is the evaluation order of the variables. The *GNU make* manual explains how it evaluates Makefiles [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles).

When the prerequisites for the recipe are expanded here:

```
sauce : $(objects) $(action) $(game)
```

`objects` has not been assigned so expands to nothing.

The expansion in the recipe:

```
     $(CXX) -o sauce $(objects)
```

Takes place as a later stage at which point `objects` has been assigned.

If you move the rule definition after the assignment to objects and action_obj as bellow it should work correctly.

```
game_obj = Game.o Game_InitializeObjects.o

action_obj = Action.o ActionManager.o Bludgeon.o Drop.o GoTo.o Murder.o Shoot.o Stab.o \
Strangle.o Take.o WaitFor.o

objects = $(game_obj) $(action_obj) $(condition_obj) $(object_obj) $(prop_obj) \
$(operator_obj) $(plangning_obj) $(world_obj) $(utilities_obj)

sauce : $(objects) $(action) $(game)
    $(CXX) -o sauce $(objects)
```

Due to the use of [recursively expanded variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) (those assigned with `=` as opposed to `:=`)  the specific order of assignment to `action_obj` and `objects` does not matter as long as they are both assigned before they get expanded.

All of the variables that are expanded as part of expanding `objects` must be assigned before the rule to make `sauce` appears in the Makefile.

Comment: Yes, all of the source files and headers are in the same directory as the makefile. The source files are all .cpp

Comment: It's technically not true that `action_obj` needs to be defined before `objects`, since both variables are recursively defined.  Although it's simpler to understand if you do define them in order.  But it _IS_ true that both variables must be defined before they appear in the prerequisite list of the `sauce` target.  Using simple (`:=`) vs. recursive (`=`) definition doesn't change that.